# Eevee motion blur messing up the animation

Tags: geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, motion-blur, image-sequence

I have a simple geo nodes explosion setup with a geo nodes system which spwans points on given mesh
[image] then with sim nodes theres is added physics

for debris i  just instanced some rocks on those points   for dust explosion i instanced some image planes with spritesheet material (using the frame function to drive the uv map in each frame)
[image]

The geo nodes setup uses a lot of simulation nodes setups and attributes
the dust trails are just point to curve node with mesh to curve and some set position displacement for some wavy motion

After rendering in eevee with motion blur i see this strange flickering in dust and trails
[image]

then i tried disabling the dust and trails and just render the debris it worked fine but when i increased the density of particles the render feels like its skipping or freezing at some frames this issue only happens with motion blur on   any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your geo nodes ? And what type of "glitch" ?

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: sorry to say AAA, but your node tree won't help anybody to help you, because it is not readable at all. And pls add images into your question, not in links in comments. thx. Always remember: you wanna have help for free from people in their spare time. So you should think about how you can make it as easy as possible to help them to help you. Another thing: GN questions are very popular and will be answered in minutes - if the question is of high quality....and has all informations. I personally don't even understand what you mean with your "glitchy" problem...so maybe you wanna explain!?

Comment: My only guess is that your geometry changes, which can be bad with motion blur. I can't help you more than that without access to your blend file. If you want to upload it : https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Hello you were right i tried disabling the set position displacement and it fixed the flickering and for the frame freezing i just had to bake the animation its working perfectly now